# C# - Loop through DataGridView Rows using foreach and if statement - Missing last entry

Tags: c#, if-statement, foreach, datagridview

I have a DataGridView with a checkbox column.

[image]

Now I want to loop through all rows, with an active checkbox and print out the `IdUser` and `True`.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in userDataGridView.Rows)
            {
                if (row.Cells[5].Value.ToString() == "True")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + " - " + row.Cells[5].Value.ToString());
                }

            }
```

In this example the  row with the `IdUser` 17 is the last selected one.

I don't know why, but I just see entry 15 as the last one. 17 is not shown any more...

Can anybody help?

---

I tried the following now:

```cs
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in userDataGridView.Rows)
            {
                msg += row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + " - " +
                     row.Cells[5].Value.ToString() + "\r\n";
            }
```

and experienced, that always the last row with a selected checkbox is somehow not recognized.

Comment: Just to understand and to know for next time: Why is this question rated with -1?

Comment: Pls look at my  answer and my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution. I added

```cs
userDataGridView.EndEdit();
```

before the loop and now the last selected checkbox is also recognized.